# Filter age from database using PHP

Tags: php, sql, database

I have a database which has a range of people with an age group. In the database the age data is showing things like 6m for 6 months, 5y for 5 years and so on. I need to be able to filter my data so I can only see the age group below 5. This is what my PHP looks like at the minute.

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT code, minimumAge, description
          FROM recalls
          WHERE startBasis='age'
          ORDER BY code";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    if($row['minimumAge'] <= 5) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['code'] . "'> "
          . $row['code'] . " " . $row['minimumAge'] . " " . $row['description'] 
          . "</option>";
    }
```

At the minute if you have someone with the age of 6m it won't show up because the number is higher than 5, how do I get it to include the information for anyone under 5y but older than 5m?

Comment: Could you explain the data type for minimumAge please. Is it a string? if it is, then that's a poor datatype for representing this information.

Comment: I think it is in a string. It contains others like [4y 2m] as well so it is badly written. I never created this database, it was created before I came to work for this company and I don't think they will allow me to edit the information from the DB.

Comment: Consider modification of table structure. Or, write filter code to sperate m and y data in between your $query and while(...)

Comment: @CheckeredMichael Why would you say 'I think'. Run the SQL 'describe your_table_name' on your database and modify your original question to show that information please.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query only records with minimumAge like '5y' or '4y' or '4y 3m' or '9m' and so on
you can use `REGEXP` operator in select query (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/regexp.html):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT code,minimumAge,description FROM recalls WHERE startBasis='age' AND minimumAge REGEXP '^([0-5]y|[0-9]m)|([0-5]y [0-9]m)&' ORDER BY code";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps without regexp just fetching the first character from minimumAge in the WHERE-clause .. ?

Too lazy to check it completely/thoroughly .. but thinking something along the lines of:

```
SELECT DISTINCT code, minimumAge, description
FROM recalls
WHERE startBasis='age'
AND ( 1 * SUBSTR( minimumAge , 1 , 1 ) ) < 6
ORDER BY code
```

So, not tested and stuff.